# colord errors in /var/log/syslog in 18.10

Tags: 18.10

I'm seeing a lot of repetitive `colord` errors in `/var/log/syslog`. I've reinstalled `colord` and `colord-data` with no help. Anybody have any ideas on how to cure this?

```
$ systemctl status colord
● colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/colord.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-12-19 08:36:40 PST; 7h ago
 Main PID: 29950 (colord)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 6.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/colord.service
           └─29950 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord

Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadFloat ::= { laEntry 6 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadInt ::= { laEntry 5 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laConfig ::= { laEntry 4 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Dec 19 08:36:40 Satellite-E55 colord[29950]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
```

Here's a snippet of what's in syslog...

```
Dec 18 06:25:26 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: failed to get session [pid 10755]: No data available
Dec 18 06:25:26 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: failed to get session [pid 10755]: No data available
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: MIB search path: /var/lib/colord/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdavis ::= { enterprises 2021 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: ucdDiskIOMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 15 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 13 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensors ::= { ucdExperimental 16 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 32 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'ucdavis' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoMIB ::= { ucdavis 14 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: ucdavis near line 7 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 9 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 8 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmp ::= { enterprises 8072 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 10 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 21 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpObjects' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpModuleIDs' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpNotifications' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpGroups' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsAgentNotifyGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 9 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 545 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 8 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 536 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigGroups ::= { netSnmpGroups 7 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 515 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 4 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 505 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsModuleGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 495 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: netSnmpAgentMIB ::= { netSnmpModuleIDs 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpModuleIDs near line 24 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactions ::= { netSnmpObjects 8 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 55 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfiguration ::= { netSnmpObjects 7 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 54 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsErrorHistory ::= { netSnmpObjects 6 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 53 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCache ::= { netSnmpObjects 5 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 52 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDLMod ::= { netSnmpObjects 4 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 51 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsExtensions ::= { netSnmpObjects 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 50 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsMibRegistry ::= { netSnmpObjects 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 49 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsVersion ::= { netSnmpObjects 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 48 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 482 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 476 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 470 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IPV6-ICMP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 12 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (INET-ADDRESS-MIB): At line 13 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmp' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'InetAddressType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'InetAddress' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExamples ::= { netSnmp 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmp near line 16 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpExamples' in module NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassExamples ::= { netSnmpExamples 255 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpExamples near line 14 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 16 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'nsExtensions' in module NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendGroups ::= { nsExtensions 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendObjects ::= { nsExtensions 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 38 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: netSnmpExtendMIB ::= { nsExtensions 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 1 in (none)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 9 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 16 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 25 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpObjects' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'netSnmpGroups' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'vacmGroupName' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'vacmAccessContextPrefix' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'vacmAccessSecurityModel' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'vacmAccessSecurityLevel' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: netSnmpVacmMIB ::= { netSnmpObjects 9 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 28 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegExCompilation ::= { logMatchEntry 101 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchErrorFlag ::= { logMatchEntry 100 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCycle ::= { logMatchEntry 11 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCount ::= { logMatchEntry 10 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 9 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCount ::= { logMatchEntry 8 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 7 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCount ::= { logMatchEntry 6 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 5 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegEx ::= { logMatchEntry 4 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchFilename ::= { logMatchEntry 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchName ::= { logMatchEntry 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchIndex ::= { logMatchEntry 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: nsVacmAccessEntry ::= { nsVacmAccessTable 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extErrFixCmd ::= { extEntry 103 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extErrFix ::= { extEntry 102 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extOutput ::= { extEntry 101 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extResult ::= { extEntry 100 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extCommand ::= { extEntry 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extNames ::= { extEntry 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extIndex ::= { extEntry 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPublic ::= { ucdDemoMIBObjects 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodTable ::= { ucdDlmodMIB 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodNextIndex ::= { ucdDlmodMIB 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExamples ::= { netSnmp 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpConformance ::= { netSnmp 5 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpNotificationPrefix ::= { netSnmp 4 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpExperimental ::= { netSnmp 9999 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpEnumerations ::= { netSnmp 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpObjects ::= { netSnmp 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionDoDebugging ::= { version 20 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionSavePersistentData ::= { version 13 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionRestartAgent ::= { version 12 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionUpdateConfig ::= { version 11 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionClearCache ::= { version 10 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionConfigureOptions ::= { version 6 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionIdent ::= { version 5 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionCDate ::= { version 4 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionDate ::= { version 3 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionTag ::= { version 2 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionIndex ::= { version 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 1 }
Dec 18 07:02:11 Satellite-E55 colord[1309]: Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheStatus ::= { nsCacheEntry 3 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed `snmp-mibs-downloader` and restarted `colord`.

```
$ systemctl status colord
● colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/colord.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-12-19 16:31:59 PST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 13421 (colord)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 17.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/colord.service
           ├─13421 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord
           └─13452 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord-sane

Dec 19 16:31:59 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Dec 19 16:31:59 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
```

source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400138

```
Some old similar errors found on Google suggest either installing
snmp or snmp-mibs-downloader.
```

Comment: I wouldn't have found that solution in a million years. Insert USB stick → color profile daemon goes wild → solution: install networking protocol downloader. Never a boring day with Linux :)

Comment: @Zilk glad I could help!