# access to Canon i-Sensys MF645 scanner via network

Tags: networking, scanner, canon, xsane

I'm sorry, I tried many things but without success, and could use some help. I have a Canon i-Sensys MF645Cx multifunction printer / scanner connected via my home LAN. Printing worked out-of-the-box, now I wanted to use the scanner.

I installed from the Canon webpage

https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys-mf645cx.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

- UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V5.10
  (printer is not shown on registration, I added the printer and its IP-address for "socket")
- CQue driver "deb"

I played around with ufw firewall rules e.g.

```
% sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8610/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8612/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8610/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8612/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and tried to edit /etc/sane.d/pixma.conf, with either line added

```
bjnp://192.168.2.100
mfnp://192.168.2.100
```

but when I start xsane (e.g. with the mfnp line activated), I get

```
% xsane
[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)
[bjnp] bjnp_init_device_structure: Cannot read mac address, skipping this scanner
[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)
[bjnp] add_scanner: ERROR - Cannot read scanner make & model: bjnp://192.168.2.100:8612/timeout=1000
```

I also tried [https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git](https://launchpad.net/%7Erolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
sudo apt-get update
```

but that didn't change anything.

I also added myself to the groups scanner and saned according to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/#Hardware, without success.

Any ideas how I can get the the scanner working? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

With some help I found the solution (Ubuntu 18.04): What I forgot was to upgrade after adding the external repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This seems the be the decisive change. The firewall can actually be disabled:

```
% sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

No changes have to be made to config files in `/etc/sane.d`. (I cannot say whether installing the two Canon packages or the group membership is important since I didn't revert these steps.)

Then xsane starts and seems to works fine with the Canon i-Sensys MF645Cx.

The only strange thing was a flood of error messages when xsane started such as `Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ...`. I followed the advice on [colord errors in /var/log/syslog in 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102926/colord-errors-in-var-log-syslog-in-18-10) and installed the package `snmp-mibs-downloader` using `sudo synaptic` (plus another package that was added as a dependency). Then the messages disappear.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, it could help others.